# Issue with R version in Azure ML Studio

Tags: r, azure-machine-learning-service

I need to install "ompr.roi" package which requires R version >= 3.4.0.

But Azure ML Studio supports R version till 3.2.2. Pls refer below screenshot,

[image: Error in Execute R Script]

Is there any way I can use this library in Azure ML Studio.

Comment: In theory, you could compile the package yourself, but it is not guaranteed to work. Version restrictions are usually there for a reason. Sounds like you should contact customer support at Microsoft?

Comment: Maybe archived package [ompr.roi version 0.6.0](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/ompr.roi/). It depends on R >= 3.2.0. Note that it imports packages ROI and ompr so you will have to check those packages versions and probably also get them from the R archives.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Azure ML Studio supports R version has been updated to 3.4.4
[image]